# The difference between revise and revision

Tags: meaning, verbs

My word editor doesn't seem to accept the past tense of the verb **revision** (revisioned). It's as though it's not interpreted as a verb, yet I did find it as a verb in online dictionaries.

I wonder if I should be using **revise** instead.

Can revision be a verb and if so what is the difference between revise and revision?

Comment: Please link to the online dictionaries. The US version of Oxford [doesn't list the verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/revision) even though such usages generally travel eastwards across the Atlantic.

Comment: Revision is a **noun**, not a verb. Note the dictionary definition: "the action of **revising**". This is easily answered by using a dictionary and I'm voting to close the question for that reason.

Comment: To get the question reopened you should edit the question and include which online dictionaries you found that list *revision* as a verb.

Comment: Except @Flater that you're incorrect. *Revision* is a verb,as well as as noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To revise means

> 1 Examine and make corrections or alterations to (written or printed matter)

and

> 2 **British English** Reread work done previously to improve one's knowledge of a subject, typically to prepare for an examination.

([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revise))

whereas *revision* (sometimes spelled *re-vision*) as a verb means

> 1  To form an image of again or afresh, esp. in one's memory; to envisage again. *Now rare.*

or

> 2 To form a new concept of; to reinterpret.

(OED)

Examples of meaning 2 from the OED include

> 1968   N.Y. Times Mag. 14 Jan. 26 (heading)    The Cold War, revisited and revisioned.
>
> 1971   New Lit. Hist. 3 16   Perhaps we can start by revisioning Modernism.
>
> 1980   Jrnl. Amer. Acad. Relig. 47 636   In being revisioned as a lover of this sort, Don Juan would be especially appropriate as a model for men.

The past tense is formed by adding *ed*.